# Hide Vega text mark if value below #

Tags: vega

I’d like to hide the text mark that labels the section if the "percent" value is less than or equal to 5. In real use, the data gets updated based on interactive use of a map, and there are many cases where there are multiple categories that end up with very small values, and display a text label for those just smashes them all together.

I’m assuming it’s fairly simple but I’m struggling to make this happen! Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Here’s my spec:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "Chart categorizing CDL values for selected location.",
  "width": 294,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 0,
  "autosize": {"type": "fit-x", "contains": "padding"},
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "categories",
      "values": [
        {"percent": 3, "color": "#d9d9d9", "name": "other"},
        {"percent": 7, "color": "#ffe269", "name": "corn"},
        {"percent": 24, "color": "#e6f5c9", "name": "pasture/hay"},
        {"percent": 31, "color": "#f4cae4", "name": "developed"},
        {"percent": 35, "color": "#b3e2cd", "name": "forest"}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {"type": "stack", "field": "percent"},
        {"type": "formula", "as": "annotatedAmount", "expr": "datum.name + ': ' + datum.percent + '%'"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "categories", "field": "y1"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "i",
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "categories"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"value": 0},
          "width": {"value": 294},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y0"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "field": "y1"},
          "fill": {"field": "color"}
        },
        "update": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 1}},
        "hover": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "i"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "y": {"field": "y"},
          "dy": {"signal": "(datum.y2 - datum.y)/2"},
          "x": {"signal": "width/2"},
          "fill": [
            {
              "test": "contrast('white', datum.fill) > contrast('black', datum.fill)",
              "value": "white"
            },
            {"value": "black"}
          ],"fillOpacity": {"field": "datum.percent <= 5 ? 0 : 1 "},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "text": {"field": "datum.annotatedAmount"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. You can use a signal.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "Chart categorizing CDL values for selected location.",
  "width": 294,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 0,
  "autosize": {"type": "fit-x", "contains": "padding"},
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "categories",
      "values": [
        {"percent": 3, "color": "#d9d9d9", "name": "other"},
        {"percent": 7, "color": "#ffe269", "name": "corn"},
        {"percent": 24, "color": "#e6f5c9", "name": "pasture/hay"},
        {"percent": 31, "color": "#f4cae4", "name": "developed"},
        {"percent": 35, "color": "#b3e2cd", "name": "forest"}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {"type": "stack", "field": "percent"},
        {"type": "formula", "as": "annotatedAmount", "expr": "datum.name + ': ' + datum.percent + '%'"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "categories", "field": "y1"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "i",
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "categories"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"value": 0},
          "width": {"value": 294},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y0"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "field": "y1"},
          "fill": {"field": "color"}
        },
        "update": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 1}},
        "hover": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "i"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "y": {"field": "y"},
          "dy": {"signal": "(datum.y2 - datum.y)/2"},
          "x": {"signal": "width/2"},
          "fill": [
            {
              "test": "contrast('white', datum.fill) > contrast('black', datum.fill)",
              "value": "white"
            },
            {"value": "black"}
          ],"fillOpacity": {"field": "datum.percent <= 5 ? 0 : 1 "},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "text": {"signal": "datum.datum.percent <5? '': datum.datum.annotatedAmount"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you – that is perfect. My mistake was trying to access the values by using datum.percent instead of datum.datum.percent.

Comment: Instead of using hard coded percentages, you can also use reactive geometry to make sure the text fits in the bounding box. That's probably a separate question though.